# Django ArrayField append, avoid race condition

Tags: python, arrays, django, postgresql, race-condition

I have a model with an `ArrayField()` and would like to append a value to it.

I can do:

```
self.my_array_field.append("foobar")
```

However, this often fails because of race conditions.

So I tried something like this:

```
self.my_array_field = F('my_array_field') + "foobar"
```

this:

```
self.my_array_field = F('my_array_field').append("foobar")
```

and this:

```
self.my_array_field = Func(F('my_array_field'), Value("foobar"), function='array_append')
```

Unfortunately all of these utterly failed.

What would you advise me to achieve this PostGreSQL statement in django?

```
UPDATE my_model SET my_array_field = array_append(my_array_field, "foobar")
```

Note that this statement is also equivalent:

```
UPDATE my_model SET my_array_field = my_array_field || "foobar"
```

Comment: hmm sorry, actually the latter solution worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this solution works fine:

```
self.my_array_field = Func(F('my_array_field'), Value("foobar"), function='array_append')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This actually works. I implemented it in overwritten save() method for a model with Value (self.word_to_append). Somehow I can't get array_cat to work though. I am passing Func(F('my_array_field'), Value(self.my_array_field), function='array_cat') and I get error back from DB. any ideas?