# How to append value to the ArrayField in Django with PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, arraylist

I have created a model with the `ArrayField` in Django Model. I am using `PostgreSQL` for the database.
I want to create new rows in the database or update the existing rows.
But I can not insert or append data to the `ArrayField`.

**Model**

```py
class AttendanceModel(BaseModel):
    """
    Model to store employee's attendance data.
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attendance_user')
    date = models.DateField()
    time = ArrayField(models.TimeField(), blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['user', 'date']]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} - {self.date}'
```

**View**

```py
attend, created = models.AttendanceModel.objects.get_or_create(user=fingerprint.user, date=attendance_date)

attend.time = attend.time.append(attendance.timestamp.time())

attend.save()
```

The `time` field does not being created or updated with the new value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33454229/11348853) I did this.

```py
from django.db.models import Func, F, Value
.
.
.
attend, created = models.AttendanceModel.objects.get_or_create(user=fingerprint.user, date=attendance_date)
attend.time = Func(F('time'), Value(attendance.timestamp.time()), function='array_append')
attend.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

> `attend.time = attend.time.append(attendance.timestamp.time())`

Here the return value of ***`list.append(...)`*** is being assigned to **`attend.time`**, which is **`None`**, thus the **`attend.time`** is not getting updated.

Try this instead,

```
attend, created = models.AttendanceModel.objects.get_or_create(
    user=fingerprint.user, date=attendance_date
)
attend.time.append(attendance.timestamp.time())
attend.save()
```